# How to set the cell size of a raster using gdalwarp?

Tags: raster, clip, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am using gdalwarp to clip a raster file. My original raster has pixel size of (30,-30). Using gdaltranslate or gdalwarp the pixelsize changes to (22, -35) and (26,-26) respectively.

Any pointers how to maintain the cell size?

Comment: -tr xres yres use 30 -30 see help http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html

Comment: `gdaltranslate` and `gdalwarp` don't change the cell size unless you tell them to do so, either directly (e.g. `-tr`) or indirectly (e.g. changing projection, etc.).  More information, particularly a `gdalinfo` report on the input raster and your exact `gdaltranslate` and/or `gdalwarp ` commands would be useful so we can see what is going on. Otherwise your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Easier way to clip a raster is by using **gdal_translate** with **-projwin** parameter to guarantee that resulting raster resolution and alignment will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, Luke, xunilk. I sorted this out using -scale(if gdal version <2.0) and -tr.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way to clip a raster is by using **gdal_translate** with **-projwin** parameter to guarantee that resulting raster resolution and alignment will be preserved.

This is the syntax for -projwin parameter:

```
-projwin xmin ymax xmax ymin
```

where xmin, ymax, xmax, ymin are referred to extent of cutting area (taken, e.g., from a shapefile).

I tried it out with this selected feature of next grid and dem raster:

[image]

Complete syntax of command was:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 454470.246964 4461525.36753 466853.946164 4449890.68243 utah_demUTM2.tif utah_demUTM2_out.tif
```

After running it, resulting raster was loaded to Map View of QGIS:

[image]
and its resolution and alignment were adequately preserved.

**Editing Note:**

With next PyQGIS code I got xmin, ymax, xmax, ymin values of **-projwin** parameter.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()  #for grid layer

feat = layer.selectedFeatures()

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = feat[0].geometry().boundingBox().toRectF().getCoords()

print xmin, ymax, xmax, ymin
```